# how to get css element text in python selenium

Tags: python, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I hope all are doing well. I have a requirement to get CSS element text from Amazon.in. The below snapshot is a quick reference.

[Enter image description here] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttsNQ.jpg)

Here is some code that I tested, as shown below.

asin.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[data-asin]").get_attribute('data-asin')

Comment: Which element did you want? You only found a single data-asin attribute. Also describe any errors and post the HTML as code.

Comment: Your code looks good. Did you face any issue/error?

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[data-asin]"}

Comment: how to get all webelements with class name prefix as "s-result-item s-asin"